# Memory is filled with nothing (dumpstate/logcat?)

Tags: nexus-5, insufficient-memory

I have a Nexus 5 that says that I don't have enough space on the phone. I have checked the storage settings (see screenshots) and it is missing half of the space.

I have searched and people recommend deleting dumpstate/logcat with `*#9900#` command, but when I enter the command nothing happen.

Any ideas?

[image: Storage screenshot]
[image: Storage screenshot]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Comment: Please start with the first-aid and links provided in our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info). Summing up single values doesn't match the numbers given on top of the screen – which might indicate some storage trouble. So if all else fails, you might need to perform a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info), though that would erase all you user data and user apps.

Answer (score 0):

As izzy deleted my previous answer (Hard reset isn't just a power off, I cant even take my battery) I repost the answer

Hard reset do the trick, link of "How to do a hard reset"

```
http://www.smartmobilephonesolutions.com/content/how-to-hard-reset-an-android-phone
```